# Count nodes in linked list, later print same nodes. How to do it efficiently?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

Say i want to go over a linked list and just count the nodes that satisfy a particular condition. Later i would print value of some field in those nodes. I could go over the list again but the bigger the list the more time it would take.
I think i read before that one option is to store the pointers of the nodes of interest in an array of pointers. Is that a good solution? Are there better solutions?
I imagine there will always be comprimise between time and space. I would like to know what is the best solution for this problem.

Comment: How often you need to update your linked list? How many elements are likely to be modified during the update?

Comment: That's something to ask my teacher! So the answer would always depend on knowing the things you stated above, right?I know arrays are good when there arent many operations on them because of quick access. Linked lists are better for operations. Any more things important for decision?

Answer (score 0):

If there are few such nodes which satisfy given condition then I think its best to store the pointer to all those nodes.

If there too many nodes which possibly can satisfy that particular condition  and you need to perform these type of operation frequently then add one extra field in node that will point to the next node which satisfy given condition.In this way next time you don't need to traverse the complete list again.

Comment: What do you mean with store pointer to all the nodes? Create another linked list? Or store in array of pointers? The second pointer is interesting it would certainly help in some cases.

Comment: In first point I meant the same thing that you suggested in question ie: make array of pointers.